# Why is this variable's type its own class?

Tags: java

The following is a paraphrase of someone else's code. In this example, what exactly is `chessSolver` and how would you use it? It looks like a variable that's being assigned to a new instance of its own class (`Game`) which seems to be overriding a method (`solver()`).

```
public class Game {
  protected solver(){}; // Will be overridden

  protected final static Game chessSolver = 
    new Game() {
      protected void solver() {
        /*...*/
      };
    };
}
```

Comment: It's a class, that overrides the `solver()` method in its implementation.

Comment: It has a difference implementation for the solver method so it needs it's own class.